# Remove Builder from Java Project in STS 3.2.0

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have maven project,Which take so much time to build the project.I come to know that it have multiple builder that's why taking so much time.On going as below 
`Project-->Properties-->Builders` ,I saw multiple type of builder how can i remove all those and keep only one `Java Builder`.
Is there any efficient way to do this except go to `Project-->Properties-->Builders` and uncheck the builder which does not require.I have multiple maven project so it's not feasible to select the builder one by one.

Any Approach Suggestion must be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settings are persisted as an XML in .project file in root directory of the project.
In my case, it looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    ...
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
           <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
           <arguments></arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        ...         
    </buildSpec>
    ...
</projectDescription>
```

I would probably write a script to find all .project files in a directory and replace the contents of the  element.

BUT:

This is a hacky solution if you know what are you doing. Personally, I would leave it there.